# Possible to reset UIButton background image?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have an application where I initially set a UIButton's background image, and then need to change it to something else later. I do realize I could just remove the original button and allocate a new button with the new image, but I'd prefer to be more efficient and reuse the object that I've already allocated. Is is possible to do this? I noticed that the currentBackgroundImage property is readonly, so when I try stuff like:

```
        [thumbnailButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [thumbnailButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[photos objectAtIndex: currentPhotoIndex] thumbnail]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

or just:

```
        [thumbnailButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[photos objectAtIndex: currentPhotoIndex] thumbnail]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I get the following:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCellContentView setBackgroundImage:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16c570'
```

Is it possible to accomplish using UIButton or do I just need delete the original button and create a new one?

Comment: Are you saying that the setBackgroundImage:forState: is not working?

Comment: @picciano - Yes, I updated with error message.

Comment: Please, say what is a edit and what is the original question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a memory management problem here.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCellContentView
>   setBackgroundImage:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x16c570'

This means that your `thumbnailButton` is not pointing at a `UIButton`, but rather a `UITableViewCellContentView`. This could happen by improper assignment or if the UIButton is deallocated (in this case you have have a dangling pointer). Run the analyzer and double check your use of the button.

`UIButton buttonWithType` returns an autoreleased instance, so you need to retain it.

Answer (score 2):

In the [UIButton class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setBackgroundImage%3aforState%3a) you can read that the method `setBackground:forState:` can be used.

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine. I think the Button has to be a Custom Button.

```
UIButton *sampleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```